# How to animate opacity of element initially positioned offscreen?

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity

Consider the following code:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above is just a standard menu and submenu, I initially hide the submenu offscreen using `left: -999em` but I'm trying to animate the opacity so the submenu fades in/out when you hover over the parent item:

```
.nav li:hover ul {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -999em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
}
```

However the menu only fades in, on mouse out it hides without the animation. I believe it's due to the `left: -999em` property, if I set it to `left: 0` it works fine but then I have this bug when the submenu toggles when you hover over it even if it's hidden. Is it possible to just animate the opacity in and out this way?

Here's a sample of the code: http://codepen.io/javiervd/pen/zseln

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you suspected, the reason for why you're not seing the opacity transition when you mouse out is because the left property makes an instant change to `left: -999em;`. So the transition is taking place when the element is out of view.

A quick fix could be to add a transition to the left property as well, but with a `transition-delay` to make it change position after the opacity transition has taken place. This way, it should fade in on `:hover` and fade out before it changes position to `left: -999em;` when you hover out.

I've never used SCSS before which you are using in your CodePen example, so I hope I haven't done any errors, but the following changes made it work for me and I think this is how you want it?

```
body {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  & > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    &:hover ul {
      left: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity .3s linear; /* Added this */
;  
    }
  }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
      background: #ddd;
    }
  }

  ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -999px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s linear, left .3s linear .3s;  /* Added this */
  }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect I completely forgot about delays, thanks for the explanation as well that's what I though it was happening